# FQL - how to get all the photos a person is tagged in

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am trying to build a page on our company web site that will show all photos our company is tagged in on facebook.  Its the left "Photos of You" tab when in the FB photo page.

Is there a way to select just those pictures for a photo wall on our site?

I'm using FQL to help speed up queries on large albums.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some FQL to select tagged photos for a specific user/page (where 123 is uid).

> SELECT object_id, pid, aid, src_big, src_small, caption, like_info,
>   comment_info, modified FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT
>   object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = 123)

Not sure if it helps, but I built an application to create photo slideshows for any Facebook user or page. Feel free to also give that a try, [Slideshow App](https://veerman.ca/slideshow)